# "Meteor run android-device" throwing a Cordova error since upgrade to Meteor 1.6

Tags: meteor

```
...
While removing plugins                     
   cc.fovea.cordova.purchase,cordova-plugin-camera,cordova-plugin-compat,cordova-plugin-device,cordova-plugin-googleplus,cordova-plugin-inappbrowser,cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp,cordova-plugin-splashscreen,cordova-plugin-statusbar,cordova-plugin-tts,cordova-plugin-whitelist,cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine,cordova-plugin-actionsheet
   from Cordova project:
   Cordova error: Plugin "cordova-plugin-actionsheet" is not present in the project. See `cordova plugin list`.
```

...

So I tried reinstalling https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-actionsheet

To no avail.. I'm totally lost. Have found references to similar issues but nothing helpful.

Comment: Facing same error. Do you find any solution? @rross

Comment: I had to roll back to 1.5 to fix the issue.